# How to load value of a memory address in a register in ASM on the LC3?

Tags: assembly, lc3

Suppose there's a value stored in memory location `x4000` and I want to load it to a Register. If the program has to be started at `x3000` how can I do this, since `PC+Offset` loads would be out of range?

Comment: Use the `LDI` instruction with the address 0x4000 stored in a nearby memory location. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14843413/547981).